# Request for more Graph Analytics example for DSE Graph 5.0.3

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

In the following link 
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dse-5-0-3-released-huge-performance-gains-for-graph-analytics

There are some examples for OLAP queries , but 
I would like to get more examples .

Can I get vertices and edges in the result query ? ( and not only groupCount() and count()) ?

Comment: Would this getting started example help you at all? http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/QuickStartStudio.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run almost anything in OLAP mode. Usually the tell if something should be run in OLTP vs OLAP mode is if the operation is heavy and not real time.

If using DataStax Studio, you can change from 'Real-time' to 'Analytics' mode using the drop down in the top right corner of each code block (see the attached image).

[image: studio]

If you're doing it programatically - you will need to use a instead of g for example `gremlin> :remote config alias g database.a` notice `database.a` instead of `database.g`

You can read more about this here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/graphAnalyticsTOC.html